CXCallObserver alternative for China region
I am developing a VOIP app which should also work in China region. I want to detect whether there are any other calls active or ended. This functionality is can be achieved using Callkit CXCallObserver. But CallKit cannot be used in China. So is there any other alternative way to achieve what CXCallObserver offers?
